# Can we execute gcore in ssh

Tags: shell, ssh, gcore

Is there a way to take core dump of a remote server from a local machine, provided if i know the process of the remote server for which i have to take the dump ?

```
gcore -o /tmp/core 24635
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have the debuginfo of that process. If that is your cusom-built application, you will probably need the same build as on the server. If it is some system application, you should be fine with downloading the debuginfo packages for it.